# javascript ajax not sending array to php on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I dig my head a lot about this topic , but every solution i tried have some error ...

after reading some posts i have tried to create a simple demo of jquery+ajax call+php , but it is not retrieving array by post method on same page

My script

```
var stuff ={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'};

    $("#btn").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : '3.php',
    data    : {result:JSON.stringify(stuff)},
    success : function(response) {
    console.log(response);            
    }    
});

});
```

and

php

```
if(isset($_POST['result'])) {
$data    = $_POST["result"];
$data    = json_decode("$data", true);
echo "key1 : ".$data["key1"];

}
```

edit : success function is fine , it is giving me response , but i am not getting data by post ...

but neither i am getting any error , not any data , How can i trace what I m doing wrong ?

Comment: Add an error handler -> `$.ajax({ options : here }).fail(function() { console.log(arguments) });` and see what you get.

Comment: How do you know that you are not getting any data? Did you check your browser console's network tab?

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything in the `success` function, so what are you expecting here ?

Comment: your code is ok, i added `success : function(response) {  alert(response); }   ` and show key1 value. try inspect from chrome .. and network to see any reponse from 3.php.  do not forget `$( document ).ready(function() {` before `$("#btn").click(function(e)`

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense. You would not be getting a response if you were not sending the POST data.

Comment: You should include your expected result and the actual result. As it stands now, it is very unclear what you are asking. You would not be logging a response in your success handler if the data was not being posted to your server.

Comment: thanx patrick , your last line made me realised my mistake , i would like to end this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['result'])) {
    $data    = $_POST["result"];
    $data    = json_decode("$data", true);
    echo "key1 : ".$data["key1"];
    die();
}

?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var stuff ={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'};


$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#btn").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : '3.php',
    data    : {result:JSON.stringify(stuff)},
    success : function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
    }    
});

});

});

</script>



<input type='button' id='btn' value='RUNN'>


<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: explain "but i am not getting data by post"

Comment: i updated the code i added a div=results and `$('#result').html(response);` this you want to show ?